# Piping not seem to work with cd | explorer in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe

I've been learning batch scripting so I came across pipes and I/O redirection.

If this works:

```
tasklist | find "winword"
```

Why does this not:

```
cd | explorer
```

I expect this command to open explorer at current working directory as `cd` without any parameters outputs current directory and:

```
explorer %directory%
```

opens explorer at `%directory%`.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The "find" program reads from stdin. explorer does not.

Comment: You can just use `explorer .` to open explorer to the current folder.

Comment: `start .`. `.` is the current directory.

Comment: Finally I converted my bunch of comments (which I have cleaned up) to an answer – I hope it helps…

Answer (score 0):

Open a Command Prompt window, type `find "blah"` and press *Enter*; you'll see it awaits user/keyboard/console input, which *STDIN* points to (press *Ctrl+Z* and *Enter* to end the prompt). Then type `echo blah` and press *Enter*; you'll notice the text `blah` is printed, so there is display/console output; this is pointed to by *STDOUT*. A pipe `|` takes the data at *STDOUT* from the left-side command and redirects it into *STDIN* for the right-side command.

Now type `explorer` into the Command Prompt window; of course an Explorer Window pops up, but what happens in the Command Prompt? right, nothing, it does not await any input at *STDIN*. So you can pipe to it but it will not care as it does not read at *STDIN*. In fact, GUI applications do generally not use *STDIN* and *STDOUT*, because these things are intended for command line applications.

Yet another example: in a Command Prompt window, type `echo C:\Windows`; quite obvious what will happen; then type `echo C:\Windows| dir`; what happens? `dir` returns the contents of the *current* directory but not of `C:\Windows`. Why? well, let's type `dir` first and see what happens: yes, `dir` shows the contents of the current directory, and it does *not* await console input; so at the right side of the pipe it receives data at *STDIN* but it simply doesn't care. You can try using `dir "C:\some\other\folder"`, without and with the pipe, the output is just the same, *STDIN* is ignored here.

The `echo`/`dir` example also demonstrates the difference between console input (*STDIN*) and command line arguments or parameters: the path in the command line `dir "C:\some\other\folder"` is such an argument, and you cannot replace it by data from *STDIN*. To understand why, you need to distinguish between *parse time* (when the command is read and parsed by the interpreter) and *run time* (when the command is actually executed): arguments already have to be present at parse time, whilst *STDIN* is only relevant during *run time*, which is later. So we can say they just never meet.

This also reflects the situation with your attempt `cd | explorer`: the latter accepts command line arguments (which anyway need to be available *before* execution, so at parse time), but it doesn't care about *STDIN*. Also the *STDOUT* data from `cd` isn't available before execution (but only during run time), so it would arrive too late anyway...

Comment: TLDR what is the solution more importantly?

Comment: Well, @OZZIE, `explorer.exe` does not support _STDIN_ and thus piping…